# The sprite objects are not smooth moving on mobile but normal in Unity Editor

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

My sprites are not moving smooth in mobile(Android/IOS). The prefab counts are 4 and at the same time there could be 7-10 prefabs in the game. They are just moving by Y axis down. Here is the code.

```
void Update()
{
    Speed = _gameManager.Speed;
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

even in videos the problem is visible.
Mobile - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uUklgT5r770nGblZea0bsEpGVErDSoZh/view?usp=share_link

Unity Editor - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o2f1uMMJtgXe3dbEOCmKjeo92vWDLKKP/view?usp=share_link

The image sizes are 540*540 if this helps

I tried changing textures, decreasing the MaxSize of the image in unity Android build, but none of that helped

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the [Update](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) method, try use the [FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) method.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Speed = _gameManager.Speed;
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

You can watch the official Unity's tutorial for the difference between the 2 methods here:
[Update and FixedUpdate](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/update-and-fixedupdate#)

A quick explanation is that `FixedUpdate()` it will run 50 times per seconds that's why it is called fixed. On the other hand `Update()` it will run as much as your device can handle, that means if your having a good enough pc it might run more than 60fps but when you test it on a mobile device it might reach the same fps as your pc and that's why you see the difference in the speed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I built and checked on mobile it was worse than Update()